# Two way binding will work in index.html in angular 4?

Tags: javascript, angular, meta-tags

Is two way binding work in index.html? I have some links and meta info in index.html. How can we set head parameters in component

```
<head>
<meta name="og:title" content={{titleValue}}>
<meta name="og:url" content={{urlValue}}>
<script src="{{scriptLink}}" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

will this approach work ? I dint find any info like this.

Answer (score 4):

No, it will not work. Angular process templates starting from the root component which is defined in the module you bootstrap the application with. I looks for this component element inside `<body>` tag of `index.html`. The bindings will only work for views defined for templates of child components of the root component.

Comment: Thank  you for your answer, But can you please update here How Can I achieve Binding in index.html? Any example would be more helpfull